# Add IAM Policy to DynamoDB Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to add a policy to a Dynamo table itself -- similar to how I can add a Bucket policy directly onto an S3 bucket. I want to prevent anybody from doing anything to my table that I don't want them doing. I know that I can specify my own roles etc. but how do I do this on the table itself?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your particular use-case? To whom would you be wanting to grant access, which is not possible via standard IAM permissions?

Comment: I was looking to restrict access to the console to view the table except for a few users. I don't think that's possible though.

Answer (score 3):

No. S3, and other older services like SQS, is actually the outlier here. Most AWS services don't have policies on the resources themselves, preferring to use IAM to control access. The [DynamoDB Security Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices-security-preventative.html) page has good recommendations.

Comment: It's not really the age of the service. For example, Amazon FSx, Elastic Inference, AWS Backup, and Cloud9 are all relatively new services and all support resource-based policies. But it is the exception, rather than the rule.